# Scrollto animated div

Tags: jquery

I have a quick question. I have a div that is hidden on page load. When a user toggles the div i use Jquery animate to open the div which is placed below the anchor div and is out of view. Is it possible to scroll to the top or slightly into the newly opened div once the animation starts? Also the div animates horizontally right now and thats what i want.

jquery

```
$('.specialOfferText').click(function() {
        $('.offerPanelTab').animate({
            width : 'toggle'
        });
    })
```

Comment: yes possible using `.scroll()`.  But what do you mean by `r slightly into the newly opened div once the animation starts`

Comment: just so that the user is taken directly to the new content. I have been trying to use the `.scroll()`. Do I have to add another jquery code or just chain it to the existing

Comment: Since you mentioned `scroll along with animation` then you have to chain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned scroll along with animation, there is an option in `.animate()` for **`scrollTop`** so you can achieve it.  Try the below code

```
$('.specialOfferText').click(function() {
        $('.offerPanelTab').animate({
            scrollTop: "add your pxs",
            width : 'toggle'
        });
    })
```